# Smarty template engine, how to check if string ends with substring in template

Tags: php, templates, smarty, template-engine, smarty3

How to check if string ends with substring from smarty3 template?

Something like:

```
{if string|ends_with:substring}
    String realy ends with substring
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php substr:

```
{if ($string|substr:N:M) == "wantedSubstring"}
    ...
{/if}
```

where N and M are your indexes for substring.

Check [substr](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) manual for syntax.